# elequent compound relationships

Tags: laravel, relationship

Compoud relationship (more one id)

```
$tickets = Ticket::with(['orders', 'order'])
    ->when($status == 'open' || $status == 'closed', function ($query) use ($status) {
        $query->where('tickets.open', ($status == 'open')? 1 : 0);
    })->when($type == 'Internal Message', function ($query) use ($type) {
        $query->where('type', $type);
    })->has('orders')
    ->orHas('order')
```

relationship

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Order::class, 'transaction_id', 'transaction_id');
}


public function order()
{
    return $this->hasOne(OrderItems::class, 'item_id', 'item_id')
        ->rightJoin('orders as o', 'order_items.order_id','=','o.id');
}
```

but when not work with relationship **order**

when i send query without order - when work, when i send with(['order']) field status not work and take all tickets

Comment: Can you post what error message, or unexpected behavior, you get?

Comment: shows no errors, the status of open select all tickets (and closed), without relationship order all status work

Comment: `with` function expects that arguments will be function name that returns `relation` object instance `orders` does it, but `order` returns `QueryBuilder` instance. Try comment `rightJoin` call.